# Kendo UI Grid MVC Helper how to NOT render "type": "aspnetmvc-ajax"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

So I've been trying out the Kendo UI grid and I initially started with just the plain non-MVC helper generated client side grid, taking data from a Web API controller via GET. Worked just fine but was starting to get messy model binding the sort and filter parameters.

So I started using the MVC helpers and ran into a problem, which is this:

When using the non-MVC generated grid, configured to use GET and with the dataSource "type" NOT SET, the GET params look like this:

```
page    1
pageSize    10
skip    0
sort[0][dir]    asc
sort[0][field]  OrderID
take    10
```

This is the correct form to bind to the DataSourceRequest MVC helper...BUT if I render said grid using the MVC extension, it sets the dataSource "type" to "aspnetmvc-ajax" which causes the GET params to look like this:

```
filter  
group   
page    1
pageSize    10
sort    OrderID-asc
```

(and if you have multiple sort params it joins them with a "~".). This second format will not bind properly to DataSourceRequest and so you end up with a null "Sorts" member....*this seems completely backwards to me because you would only have the DataSourceRequest helper if you were using the MVC extension - but when you use them, the data is being sent incorrectly*!

I also tried POSTing to a regular MVC Controller as per the examples and had the same problem.

In any case, I'm trying to find a way to tell the extension to not render the aspnetmvc-ajax. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so the solution was to use the model binder provided for webapi found in the sample code here:

[Kendo UI Grid Params model binder for Web API](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/binding-to-a-web-apicontroller.aspx)

which I found quite by accident....Of course, that's just the beginning of my "adventure" with Kendo UI....

Comment: @BenjaminDeClercq - what sort of information do you need? Please bear with me as this was over two years ago so if you're having a similar problem the answer might not even be relevant any more (Kendo UI has improved a lot in the last 2 years!)

Comment: How do u use the provided model binder correctly?
I want to use the GET-http-method to call the function on my controller.
When I try to use the provided model binder no binding happens, and when I use [FromUri] I get the paging... but no sorting or filtering...

Comment: @BenjaminDeClercq - in my case I literally copied their code...I would say that posting a new question about this is the best idea, since as I mentioned things have changed a lot with Kendo UI in the last 2 years, so this solution might not even work any more. If you post the link to the question here, I'll do my best to help :)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm writing my own modelbinder now because the one provided doesn't work for me. I'm not using Telerik ASP.NET MVC but Telerik Kendo UI (html), I'm using WebApi v1.x, no OData, and I want to use GET-request for read operations. So I'm setting the type of the dataSource to 'json' instead of 'apsnetmvc-ajax' and the data binding has to be done differently in that case.

Comment: They also don't recommend using 'aspnetmvc-ajax' on it's on.

"Odata is the only one type that should be used by end users. Aspnetmvc-ajax is used by Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC to perform the Ajax binding and we do not recommend to use it on its own." - http://www.telerik.com/forums/what-are-the-possible-types-of-data-transports#ZFDsohNKHUqEbHoewi23UA

Comment: @BenjaminDeClercq - indeed. My original problem was that this type was being auto-rendered by the Kendo MVC helpers and I wanted to stop that because it was not working as expected.  In any case if you are using WebAPI then read this article: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/the-facts-on-using-kendo-ui-with-asp-net-webapi In it you will find a link to a github sample app that contains a DataRequest binder for WebAPI that should work just fine with the Kendo UI Grid (in particular https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/tree/master/grid-webapi-crud).

Answer (score 2):

The MVC Extensions are using the aspnet-ajax transport settings and they are bound to the DataSourceRequest object if you use the DataSourceRequest attribute which will handle the binding. Check the controller code of the [demos](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html).

```
    public ActionResult EditingCustom_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(SessionClientProductRepository.All().ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Petur, but I don't think this is the solution. My problem is that when the grid is rendered using the MVC helper, the format of the data that it sends in Ajax GET mode doesn't correctly map into the DataSourceRequest object. I'm already using FromUri and DataSourceRequest attributes on the request parameter and for example paging is working just fine.
But e.g. the "Sorts" member is always null because the data should have been sent in the first format, but is being sent in the second;

Comment: You probably forgot to include kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js. Check the documentation: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction#manually-add-kendo-ui-to-asp.net-mvc-applications

Comment: Thanks but that's not it either. Actually I found the solution buried in a blog on the kendo ui site..see answer for link.